# Genetic Algorithms in Python: Split an Organism List in Half According to Higher Fitness

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, genetics

I need to sort an organisms list according to fitness. The code below generates a random list-'organism'-according to user input. However there is a bug and the list only sometimes sorts. After there is the sorted list, I need to take half of. The higher fitness values-the sum of each organism-is what determines which organism is in the top half.

```
import random as randint

    pop_size = int(input('Enter a population size:'))
    length = int(input('Enter an organism length:'))

    orgs = []
    for i in range(pop_size):
        org = []
        for a in range(length):
            org.append(randint.randint(0,1))
        orgs.append(org)

    print sorted(orgs, key=sum)
```

Explanations are much appreciated, I'm a beginner and am trying to improve.

Comment: `sorted` will give you the outer list sorted in ascending order of the sublist sum. You would want `sorted(orgs, key=sum, reverse=True)` - depending on how you define "top half" which I'm assuming is index 0.

Comment: I still sometimes get an output where it is ranked as 0 3 0, or out of order. Top half refers to highest fitness.

Comment: Ok, then do you assign the list back to a variable (I assume you don't just have `print` in your actual code). `sorted` does not work in-place so you'd need `orgs = sorted(orgs, key=sum, reverse=True)`. In other words, your sort would never work unless you do it that way and any sorted sublists are currently coincidental.

Comment: orgs = sorted(orgs, key=sum, reverse=True)
print orgs
Like that? If I input 4 and 2 the fitness is still 1, 1, 0, 1

Comment: Change `print sorted(orgs, key=sum)` to `orgs = sorted(orgs, key=sum, reverse=True)` then on the line below, `print orgs`.

Comment: That's what I have, but I'm still getting some input that is incorrectly sorted. import random as randint

pop_size = int(input('Enter a population size:'))
length = int(input('Enter an organism length:'))

orgs = []
for i in range(pop_size):
    org = []
    for a in range(length):
        org.append(randint.randint(0,1))
    orgs.append(org)
    
orgs = sorted(orgs, key=sum, reverse=True)
print orgs

Comment: Then there is something else going on in your code. I cannot replicate the issue and wouldn't expect to either.

Comment: Ok, how would I divide the list into two? And a question: why is there no space in between key=sum?

Comment: You need to look into "list slicing" to get half the list. PEP8 is the format guidance for Python and suggests that keyword arguments, specifically, do not have a space either side of the `=`. It does nothing to change functionality.  Your first port of call should be investigating your sorting issue.